# Is there an "open sets style" formulation of Topology that makes the connection to semidecidability precise?

Tags: general-topology, computability

Once pointed out, the connection between Topology - the definition of what open sets are - and semidecidability (as used in Computer Science) is clear. $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are semidecidable, and any finite intersection of semidecidable sets is also semidecidable - run the semidecision process for each set in sequence. But it is not the case that an arbitrary union of semidecidable sets is also a semidecidable set. We come close; "recursively enumerable unions" ($RE$) of semidecidable sets are also a semidecidable set.

So my goal with this question is to obtain a generalized definition of open sets, one that relaxes the "arbitrary" closure condition in the regular definition to something that accepts semidecidability. In principle, we could just replace that with $RE$ as suggested before, but that would give us a definition that isn't really applicable to general topology.

The reference text for this seems to be Martin Escardó's work, specifically [Synthetic topology of data types and classical spaces](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/entcs87.pdf). But as a beginner in Topology myself, i've found the paper difficult to understand. His approach - using continuous functions as the primary component, upon which the rest of definitions are laid out - makes it hard to appreciate the connection. Which is why i'm asking specifically for an "open sets style" definition.

Comment: It's might be easier to redefine "set." :) In constructive mathematics, the only sets are constructible, so then if $X$ is a set $P(X)$ is the set of constructive sets, but you don't get a boolean algebra, but you do get that the union of any (constructive) set of (constructive) sets is a constructive set, so that $P(X)$ in that sense is a topology rather than a boolean algebra.

Comment: That's a cheeky solution :-) But for now i'd rather stick to classical mathematics. Like i said, i'm a beginner still, and while i like constructivity, most beginner-oriented material in Topology deals with classical math. In other words; i'd like to be able to read a textbook like Munkres and appreciate the connection to semidecidability (in lieu of an analysis background, which as someone who did compsci in college is something i don't have).

Comment: I certainly didn't mean it as an answer, just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: It's certainly an unusual extension of the idea of topology, because every singleton is open but not ever set is open.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If it makes you feel better, you can think about the set of computable $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ functions instead (with its semidecidable properties as the "topology"). For a moment i thought this wouldn't work due to Rice's Theorem, but then i realized it states that there aren't undecidable non-trivial properties. Taking out the double negation, it means the non-trivial properties can still be semidecidable (and it's easy to think of examples). In fact, Rice's Theorem has topological content - it says the computable function space is connected.